# Python - Extract multiple values from string in pandas df

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I've searched for an answer for the following question but haven't found the answer yet. I have a large dataset like this small example:

```
df =

A  B
1  I bought 3 apples in 2013
3  I went to the store in 2020 and got milk
1  In 2015 and 2019 I went on holiday to Spain
2  When I was 17, in 2014 I got a new car
3  I got my present in 2018 and it broke down in 2019
```

What I would like is to extract all the values of > 1950 and have this as an end result:

```
A  B                                                    C
1  I bought 3 apples in 2013                            2013
3  I went to the store in 2020 and got milk             2020
1  In 2015 and 2019 I went on holiday to Spain          2015_2019
2  When I was 17, in 2014 I got a new car               2014
3  I got my present in 2018 and it broke down in 2019   2018_2019
```

I tried to extract values first, but didn't get further than:

```
df["C"] = df["B"].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(int)
df["C"] = df["B"].apply(lambda x: re.search(r'\d+', x).group())
```

But all I get are error messages (I've only started python and working with texts a few weeks ago..). Could someone help me?

Comment: Should 1950 be included? Do you want to also extract `19555` and more-digit numbers?

Comment: You can use [this](https://regex101.com/r/IRlb14/2/)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I haven't come that far, but I was thinking that: because I need the year it took place, filtering the number after I extracted them with >1950 I will get the years and loose the other unusefull values.

Comment: I would use something like `df["C"] = df["B"].str.findall(r'(?<!\d)(?:19[5-9]\d|[2-9]\d{3}|\d{5,})(?!\d)').str.join('_')` that also includes 1950 and 5+ digit numbers.

Comment: If you only need 4 digit years, remove `|\d{5,}` from the above. To exclude `1950` add `(?!1950)` / `(?!1950(?!\d))` after `(?<!\d)`. Only use it if your input is completely messed up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With single regex pattern (considering your comment "*need the **year** it took place*"):

```
In [268]: pat = re.compile(r'\b(19(?:[6-9]\d|5[1-9])|[2-9]\d{3})')

In [269]: df['C'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: '_'.join(pat.findall(x)))

In [270]: df
Out[270]: 
   A                                                  B          C
0  1                          I bought 3 apples in 2013       2013
1  3           I went to the store in 2020 and got milk       2020
2  1        In 2015 and 2019 I went on holiday to Spain  2015_2019
3  2             When I was 17, in 2014 I got a new car       2014
4  3  I got my present in 2018 and it broke down in ...  2018_2019
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way using [`str.findall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.findall.html) and joining those items from the resulting lists that are greater than `1950`::

```
s = df["B"].str.findall('\d+')
df['C'] = s.apply(lambda x: '_'.join(i for i in x if int(i)> 1950))

   A                                                  B          C
0  1                          I bought 3 apples in 2013       2013
1  3           I went to the store in 2020 and got milk       2020
2  1        In 2015 and 2019 I went on holiday to Spain  2015_2019
3  2             When I was 17, in 2014 I got a new car       2014
4  3  I got my present in 2018 and it broke down in ...  2018_2019
```

Comment: So, I've got an additional question. What if I only want to keep the earliest year?

Comment: Try playing a bit with `min` @lotw

Comment: Yes that I got. My problem is how I can neatly do it. Now I got:
df2 = df['C'].str.split('_', expand=True)
df2 = df2.fillna(0).astype(int)
df2.columns = ['C{}'.format(col) for col in df2.columns ]
df = df.join(df2)
Which is a big workaround to split C again. I would like it to take the smallest number directly..